# Simulated annealing in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

Good afternoon.

I need to solve the problem with time windows using the road graph, where the client’s and depot’s working hours are limited in time. I load the initial data on the problem from my file.
How to set correctly in the configuration the Algorithm for simulating annealing and hard rules in drops by capacities and time windows? I need an example of a working configuration.

```
    //my loader problem from json file
    Loader loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(AppConfig.CURRENT_DIR + "\\" + "problem_cvrptw.json");
    InputBuffer buf = loader.getBuf();

    //set problem
    TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution problem = new TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution();
    problem.setCustomerList(buf.getCustomers());
    problem.setDepotList(buf.getDepots());
    problem.setVehicleList(buf.getVehicles());
    problem.setLocationList(buf.getLocations());
    problem.setDistanceType(DistanceType.ROAD_DISTANCE);
    problem.setDistanceUnitOfMeasurement(null); //not "sec"

    //build solver
    SolverConfig solverConfig = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource("vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml");
    SolverFactory<TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(solverConfig);
    Solver<TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution> solver =  solverFactory.buildSolver();

    //solve 
    TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution solution = solver.solve(problem);
```

How to create a configuration to solve the problem with the annealing algorithm using SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig ()?

Answer (score 0):

**In XML, [just follow this docs section](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#simulatedAnnealing).** It will look like this:

```
<localSearch>
    ...
    <acceptor>
      <simulatedAnnealingStartingTemperature>2hard/100soft</simulatedAnnealingStartingTemperature>
    </acceptor>
</localSearch>
```

If you want to avoid using XML, you can do something like this:

```
solverConfig = new SolverConfig(...).withPhases(
       new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig(),
       new LocalSearchPhaseConfig.withLocalSearchType(LATE_ACCEPTANCE));
```

Now, instead of `LATE_ACCEPTANCE` you could use `SIMMULATED_ANNEALING`, but that can't work without a startingTemperate, so you 'll have to do something like `withAcceptor().with...`.